# For a bounded set A, there is a sequnce contained in A that converges to inf(A)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

Let A be a bounded subset of R. Prove that there is an infinite sequence (Xn)
 such
that xn ∈ A for every n, and lim n→∞
xn = inf(A).

My attempt:
Let inf(A)= a. Then since a is a greatest lower bound for A, there exists an xn ∈ A such that: a < xn < inf + 1/2. The same is true for inf + 1/3, inf+ 1/4,..., inf + 1/n. This selection of xn's based on 1/n gives a sequence contained in A.

I'm not sure if I my construction of the sequence needs more detail. From here, I need to show this sequnce converges to a using the epsilon definition of a limit, but I'm struggling with manipulating this 'implicitly' described sequence. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have a doubt. If you take the set ${0}\cup [1,2]$, it is a bounded subset of $R$. But there is no subsequence of your type that converges to $\inf A =0$ except for the trivial one... And I'm interpreting your inequalities as you've written them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose on the contrary that $\exists n$ such that there $[a, a+\frac1n) \cap A =\emptyset$, then $a+\frac1n$ is a lower bound of $A$ which violates $a$ being the greatest lower bound.

Hence we can always choose $x_n \in [a,a+\frac1n]$

Hence by construction, we have $|x_n - a| \le \frac1n$.

Hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n-a| \le \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n = 0$$

Remark: If you want to use an explicit $\epsilon$ definition of a limit , just choose $N > \frac1{\epsilon}$.